# Angular 2 refresh cache of http.get

Tags: angular, http, caching, get, browser-cache

It seems like my http.get caches the website it gets. I have to force clear the cache(CTRL+F5) to get it to get the newest version. And idea how to get it to clear the cache automatically? Also, I don't have access to the other site(Can't set headers :/)

Thank you!

The code I used:

```
public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
  // return this.http.get('URLTOHTML', )
             .map(res => Object(res.json()));
}
```

Behavior: It only gets the newest data when I force clear the cache with CTRL+F5

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added the code and behavior

Comment: Is this only in IE/Edge or also in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can't use IE/Edge(Linux), Chrome and Firefox same behavior

Comment: `http.get` doesn't cache anything. IE is known to cache AJAX requests. I doubt your issue is caused by Angular.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Meh, any idea to fix it?

Comment: No, because I have no idea what the problem is. I'm pretty sure though, it's not related to Angular.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Okay, thank you!